# get file path using backslash (\) in windows in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to get result exactly the same format as follows?

```
result = ( C:\data\a.jpg C:\data\b.jpg C:\data\c.jpg )
```

The following code fails:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob ('*.jpg')
for file in files:
  result = "C:\data\" + file
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are you looking for [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)?

Comment: @ inspectorG4dget i also tried os.path.join but could not make with backslashes

Comment: `os.path.join("c:", "foo", "bar.png")`

Comment: Or `r'C:\data\{}'.format(file)` to avoid the `\\` at the end of a string problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os, glob
files = glob.glob('*.jpg')
files = [os.path.join("C:\\data", file) for file in files]
result = "( " + " ".join(files) + " )"
print result  # Prints ( C:\data\a.jpg C:\data\b.jpg C:\data\c.jpg )
```

(You might want to use `os.getcwd()` rather than the literal `"C:\\data"`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to split the back  slash as well
like this:

```
person_names.add(image_path_names[-1].split('/')[0].split('\\')[1])
```