# Finding file in directory using python and wildcard

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I find a file in directory using python. I tried using glob but not able to get consistant results

I need to find this file but glob does not seem to pick it up.
D:\Temp\projectartifacts\drop\projectartifacts\vendor.c252f50265ea4005a6d8.js

```
glob.glob('D:\Temp\projectartifacts\drop\projectartifacts\vendor.*.js')
```

Comment: what results are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Comment: Please tell us more details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get file path using backslash (\‌) in windows in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756485/get-file-path-using-backslash-in-windows-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the python regex library to find the desired pattern in a specific folder.
If you have the folder path, you just have to check all files names against this regex.

```
import os
import re

# Create the list of all your folder content with os.listdir()
folder_content = os.listdir(folder_path)

# Create a regex from the pattern
# with the regex, you want to find 'vendor.' --> 'vendor\.' (. needs to be escaped)
# then any alphanumeric characters --> '.*' (. is regex wildcard and .* means match 0 or more times any characters)
# then you want to match .js at the end --> '\.js'

regex_pattern = 'vendor\..*\.js'
regex = re.compile(regex_pattern)

# Search in folder content
res = ''
for path in folder_content:
    if regex.search(path):
        res = path
        break

print(res)
```

Comment: how is re defined?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to put the imports ! re is a standard python library. I edited the post